# how to check drop down is selected or not using watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

**I want to check whether dropdown is selected or not**

```
if(ie.select_list(:id, "DropDownList").selected?)#this is wrong
  puts "selected"
else
   puts "not selected"
end
```

**how can I check this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here [`find out the value in select list`](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/classes/Watir/SelectList.html#M000678)

```
ar_vals = ie.select_list(:id, "DropDownList").selected_options
ar_vals.empty? ? puts "not selected" : puts "selected"
```